# Running composer by shell_exec or passthru don't work

Tags: php, composer-php, web-deployment, shell-exec

I'm trying to running an PHP code from a URL so when the URL is opened the script must to run at server (Nginx).

URL example: https://my-server.com/deploy.php

I have 3 code blocks inside this script:

1. git pull (works fine);
2. rm -rf vendor (works fine);
3. composer install (not worked);

Trying to debug, I change this part of code to:

```
$composer = shell_exec('composer install 2>&1');
echo "$composer";
```

Note: before use **shell_exec** I try with **passthru** and this didn't work too.

So I got this error:

```
sh: 1: composer: not found
```

And another time this error:

```
[RuntimeException]
The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly
```

If a run the same file by SSH command, like:

```
php deploy.php
```

The code works fine and execute the composer install.

At first I thought could be the file permission, so I change to 777 and the error keeps happen.

Why the composer command didn't work when is called by URL? Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: PATH and HOME will differ for the Apache-run PHP setup.

Comment: Do you know how find the PATH e HOME values in Nginx Server?

Comment: Probably /etc/default/nginx, or perhaps PHPs fpm pool config `env[PATH]`?

Comment: I got at composer documentation, in my case was /home/<user>/.composer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this, like Mario sad in comments adding the COMPOSER_HOME value.

So my code do like this:

```
$composer = shell_exec('
    export COMPOSER_HOME=/home/[user]/.composer;
    composer install 2>&1'
);
echo "$composer";
```